# How do I install an SSL certificate in Apache2?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, ssl

I am pretty new to this community and I hope I put my question on the right place.

I have bought this [SSL certificate](https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-positivessl), which comes with four files named like this:

- `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt`
- `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt`
- `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt`
- `mydomain_com`

Following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04), I end up with this error:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Action 'start' failed.
```

So my apache2 service cannot even start.

Here is what i have done in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain_com.ca-bundle.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

After I made these changes and tried to restart my apache service, I got the error shown above. These are the only changes I have done. I have not changed anything else.

Here is the error log report:

```
[Wed Jul 01 16:05:47.436945 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10568] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 01 16:05:47.436988 2015] [core:notice] [pid 10568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jul 01 16:17:27.699364 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10568] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 01 16:17:28.754414 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10729] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Jul 01 16:17:28.754465 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10729] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for mydomain.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 01 16:17:28.754485 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10729] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Wed Jul 01 16:17:28.754510 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10729] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
[Wed Jul 01 16:17:28.754514 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10729] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Wed Jul 01 16:20:56.686346 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10920] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Jul 01 16:20:56.686411 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10920] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for mydomain.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 01 16:20:56.686425 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10920] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Wed Jul 01 16:20:56.686441 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10920] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
[Wed Jul 01 16:20:56.686446 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10920] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Wed Jul 01 16:46:22.422767 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 11024] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Jul 01 16:46:22.422831 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 11024] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for mydomain.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 01 16:46:22.422844 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11024] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Wed Jul 01 16:46:22.422858 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11024] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
[Wed Jul 01 16:46:22.422862 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11024] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
```

If it is important, I have generated my key with openssl.

Note that I have replaced my real domain name and adress with `mydomain.com` for this question.

Can you please give me step by step guide how can i install this certificate on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2.

Comment: http://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/203482651-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate-on-Apache

Comment: You need to spcify SSLCertificateChainFile also. Other how to is for self signed certificates.

Comment: And which file is the chain file ? I have included all other files exept mydomain_com.crt in mydomain_com.ca-bundle.crt.

Comment: Follow the tutorial in the link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this line, where yourDomainName.ca-bundle should be prefferably a .crt file you obtained from Comodo:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/yourDomainName.ca-bundle
```

into the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

Source: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/637/37/certificate-installation-apache--mod_ssl